# Trying to register default QuartzSchedulerMBean

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, jmx

I'm trying to register the default QuartzSchedulerMBean in my JMX server running in tomcat. The `Scheduler` is obtained via spring using the `SchedulerFactoryBean`. The issue I am running into is that `QuartzSchedulerMBeanImpl` requires a `QuartzScheduler`, while the Factory yields a wrapper object (`StdScheduler`). I am able to obtain the QuartzScheduler using reflection, but I'd like to register the Mbean the correct way. So far the only documentation I've found is registering the MBean within JBoss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the "org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true" property in the quartz config?